# UITabBar Functionality

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

TabBar should not be enable any of tabs untill user clicked on any one of tab,
Below is the code I write to display tab bar, But the problem by defaultly  it is showing the first tab.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    PeopleViewController *peopleViewController = [[PeopleViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:peopleViewController];
    [peopleViewController setTitle:@"People"];

    EventsViewController *eventsViewController = [[EventsViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:eventsViewController];
    [eventsViewController setTitle:@"Events"];

    ActiveViewController *activeViewController = [[ActiveViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:activeViewController];
    [activeViewController setTitle:@"Active"];

    MoreViewController *moreViewController = [[MoreViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nav4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:moreViewController];
    [moreViewController setTitle:@"More"];

    NSArray *arrViewControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3,nav4, nil];

    [tabBarController setViewControllers:arrViewControllers];
    [self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: This is the default behavior of UITabBarController, are you asking how to change this behavior?

Comment: @Guillaume Algis yes i want to change it.Is it possible to change like that?If possible please help me

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBOutlet for the tab bar (e.g. `theTabBar`) and use following code:

`[theTabBar setSelectedItem:nil];`

Comment: >App is crashing there as following error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Comment: From the docs: "You should never attempt to manipulate the UITabBar object itself stored in this property. If you attempt to do so, the tab bar view throws an exception."

Comment: @  Guillaume Algis : Is there any other option like can we know when tab item is selcted second time?

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior of `UITabBarController`, by default first tab is selected.
You have the option to make some other tab to be selected at first instance, but cannot change the default selected to null.

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

By default selected index is 0, this is first tab, you can change it as per your requirement to 1,2,3.

Comment: @ user3982359 : Is there any other option like can we know when tab item is selected second time?